# How to export and validate data from Google sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, passwords

I have created a contact form using Google form ([link](https://forms.gle/sJBatEu7LQPPoWXP8)) and also created a very basic contact form using html code ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/ijeet/ijeet.github.io/blob/master/form.html)) [(here is GitHub page)](https://ijeet.github.io/form.html) and linked them. Now I want to create a username and password for in same manner with sign up for one time. So when a user sign up, his username and password will be saved in my Google sheets and when he will log in with the username and password, the data from Google sheets will be validate with the log in input. How to do it?
I am beginner here and this is just for learning purpose. Thanks.

Comment: You should not be doing this. Passwords should be stored on a secure server with one way hashing/salting etc. If you make a form with a password field, people will end up putting real passwords in, which you could then see in plain text.

Comment: I know that. I need server side to validate password and hash key and so on. But I'm just learning html and want to see if any way is there to  do it.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this from the client side with just HTML/CSS/Javascript as you wouldn't be able to retrieve the password from google sheets without sharing the whole sheet with all the details with everyone.

Comment: So if I make the sheet public, will I able to that?

Comment: If you are trying to learn web development and want to build a login page I would start with looking into integrating with github/microsoft/google login. The only way to do it properly with a username and password would be to start with a basic backend server.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is integrating with those websites free? Because I am student.

Comment: Yeah, they are free. If you do a quick search there will be plenty of guides of how to get setup.